# Connection between exponential distribution and uniform distribution

Tags: uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have two random variables (RV). For RV1, I generate random numbers from the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$, then keep those above a certain treshold $y$, and define the RV as the difference $x$ between those $y$ values, i.e. how long it took to generate a number above the treshold.

[image]

In the picture, the RV is thus the distance on the x-axis between the blue points above the red line, ignoring the points below the redline.

My second RV, RV2, is simply the exponential distribution, with $\lambda$.

I experimented, and when I e.g. chose the treshold $y=0.9$ and $\lambda=9$ for the exponential distriubtion then the resulting distributions look very similar. My questions is, are they connected, and if yes, how?

[image]

Orange is the exponential (RV2, 100000 samples), Blue is the transformed treshold uniform distribution (RV1, 100000 samples).

In particular, I am am simulating some process, and would like to generate arrival times that are exponentially distributed, and i am wondering if I can just sample from a uniform distribution at every iteration and when the value is above a treshold I define the trial to be a succes, otherwhise not. I am interested whether that process would have exponential interarrival times.

Also maybe the geometric distributino would be better suited but I am not sure.

Code for reproduction

````
N = 100_000
x = np.arange(N)
y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, N)
treshold = 0.9

plt.plot(x,y, alpha=0.5, marker=".", linestyle="")
plt.hlines(treshold, 0, N, color="red")
plt.show()

above_treshold = x[y > treshold]
times_until_above_treshold = np.diff(above_treshold)

plt.hist(times_until_above_treshold, alpha=0.4, bins=np.arange(0, 50))

y2 = np.random.exponential(scale=9, size=len(above_treshold))

plt.hist(y2, alpha=0.4, bins=np.arange(0, 50))

y2 = np.random.geometric(p=0.1, size=len(above_treshold))

plt.hist(y2, alpha=0.4, bins=np.arange(0, 50))

plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the question while typing.

But in short, **my experiment** with sampling numbers and accepting if above a certain treshold **is the geometric distribution**.

The geometric is the discrete version of the exponential distribution however I dont feel confident explaining exactly how they are connected, though there are many ressources on that.

They indeed look very similar in this picture (100_000 realisations)

[image]

Blue is my experiment, Orange is geometric, with $p=1-y$.